# CRUD operation functions for SharePoint Online in JavaScript

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript

I have lots CRUD operations in my project. I want to write generic function for same and include them in a single JS file. I will send relevant parameters to them and thereby achieve the required.

Please guide.

Comment: I am assuming you performing CRUD operations on custom lists

Comment: yes.. i am CRUD operation on custom list

Answer (score 1):

Here is a small JS library I built which does the basic operations. There is not much documentation as of now, but you can understand by reading comments in JS

[SPOUtilities](https://sharepointatwork.wordpress.com/2015/08/05/sharepoint-js-utility-library/)